# Disabling sound effects and haptic feedback for menu button

Tags: android, audio

I got sound effects disabled for my on-screen buttons by setting the soundEffectsEnabled attribute to false. I also need to disable sound effects and haptic feedback for the menu button. How can I do that?

Thanks