# How to turn off physical button's sound click (sound effects) in my Android app?

Tags: android, button

I'm developing an Android app where the user is allowed to rest his hand on the device, and I want to disable physical buttons so the user don't get annoyed by unwanted clicks.

I've disabled the **back**, **menu** and **search** buttons with the following:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {return false;}

@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {return false;}
```

And I've learned that disabling the **home** key is unsupported and/or not adviced (although I'd like it to).

Ok, now I couldn't figure out how to disable the clicking sound for the keys  I've disabled, they do nothing but keep ticking, is there a way to turn it off?

I'd like to **mute** it for my app only. If not possible, I'd like to know about alternatives that change system settings programmatically, to restore it latter on closing or on focus changing.

Comment: @Keyser I'd look around a lot and couldn't find. There're other similar questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114365/disabling-sound-effects-and-haptic-feedback-for-menu-button) on this same topic that are unanswered. I'd like to see a mention of which attribute in specific do that.

Comment: I withdraw my statement :p Not sure anymore. But you can set system sound volume with the [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html). Of course, this is for all apps, but you could restore the previous volume in both onPause and onStop to make it seem as if only your app is affected (though I don't know how you'd fix it with incoming calls. some listener?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can mute the sound when your app starts and unmute when it finishes

```
@override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
}


@override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try this when I get back home.

Comment: You need to receive more love for that answer! thanks