# disable android 'default sound' from hardware 'back' button

Tags: android

Ok, if we want to disable android 'default sound' from hardware 'back' button

**if it is object in android**

We can disable it by

```
onClick (View v) {
    v.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false); 
}
```

or disable it through xml by

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bSignin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" 
/>
```

**however, if it is hardware button**

how to do that ?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
    {
    // ?
    }
}
```

NOTE: i don't want to completely disable all sound, i just want to disable default sound and play my application sound instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757942/how-to-turn-off-physical-buttons-sound-click-sound-effects-in-my-android-app) and wanted to share it, as I was able to disable the hardware default back button with this solution.  Here's the code:

```
@override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
}


@override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
}
```

Comment: Is it going to mute the music playing?

Comment: I used this to prevent sounds outside my application from playing, like notification sounds from buttons.  Then, I used my own instances of classes like MediaPlayer, SoundPool, etc to play my custom sound files from res/raw.  My sounds still play :-)

Comment: Nice. Good to know that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to disable 'sound' not disable 'button'

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is possible.

There is an option in the System Settings for the user to do that. The hardware back button is not the part of your application. It is user's job to decide if they want to hear it or not. You cannot decide that.

Comment: however when they click back in my application, it's a part of my application... so what's should i do?

Comment: I told you it is not possible. If you have room access, then you can access the system preference files and disable all click sounds. This is possible and yet hard to do. Without root access you cannot change this system behavior.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, tasomaniac.  You can mute the audio system service in onResume() and turn it back on in onPause(), please see my answer.